# Generally will the power output from a heat engine increase as the work from this engine increases?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, power, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

Generally speaking, does increasing a heat engine's work will essentially increase the power output? Whether this heat engine was a turbine, vechile or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about the work performed by a heat engine we usually mean the work per cycle. Power output, on the other hand, is work done per unit time. So

$$\text{Power }=\frac{\text{Work per cycle}}{\text{Time per cycle}}$$

If we keep time per cycle constant then power is proportional to work per cycle. But if we vary time per cycle, we can have high work per cycle with low power or low work per cycle with high power, or any combination we like.